# FileHelperEngine returns List<object> instead of List<T>

Tags: c#, automapper, filehelpers

I'm using FileHelper nuget package to parse a flat file into custom DTO list class. In the beginning of my development, I hard coded the FixedFieldLength in a class file which had the list of members declared and I used that class to build the filehelperengine, but later we decided to create the field length dynamically and used below code to create the classBuilder

```
private FixedLengthClassBuilder BuildFixedLengthClass(string mplFileType)
{
    var layoutDetails = GetLayoutDetailsFromDatabase();

    const string className = "My_Dynamic_Class";
    var fixedLengthClassBuilder = new FixedLengthClassBuilder(className);

    foreach (var column in layoutDetails)
    {
        dynamic dynamicColumn = column;

        fixedLengthClassBuilder.AddField(dynamicColumn.FieldName, 
            dynamicColumn.NumberOfCharacters, dynamicColumn.Data_Type);

        if (dynamicColumn.Data_Type == "DateTime")
        {
            fixedLengthClassBuilder.LastField.Converter.Kind =
                FileHelpers.ConverterKind.Date;
            fixedLengthClassBuilder.LastField.Converter.Arg1 = "yyyyMMdd";
        }
    }
    return fixedLengthClassBuilder;
}
```

Now, I use the object returned from above method to create the FileHelperEngine as below

```
var fileHelperEngine = new FileHelperEngine(classBuilder.CreateRecordClass())
var parseResult = fileHelperEngine.ReadFileAsList(fileName);
```

Now, the `parseResult` will be `List<object>` where it has to be `List<T>`

The `fileHelperEngine` returns `List<T>` when we **do not pass** the `classBuilder.CreateRecordClass()`

Because of this, I had to loop each records and convert to respective type. I believe, I can't use **Automapper** even to convert, because object's properties are not visible to be converted.

Is this something needs to be added in this library, or is that something I'm missing?

Comment: `List<T>` is compiletime vs `new FixedLengthClassBuilder(className)` is runtime. How would it know what `<T>` it should return? Technically; A `List<T>` can be created, but it will be returned as `IList`

Comment: So when I used in my old code, I pass the `<T>` in my method and create like this var `fhEngine = new FileHelperEngine<myClass>()`, so it returned `List<T>`, whereas when I pass the `classBuilder`, it doesn't accept generic type?

Comment: Where are you passing the `const string className = "My_Dynamic_Class";` as `<T>` parameter? thats why... In your example `fhEngine = new FileHelperEngine<myClass>()` you do.. but not in the example provided above.

Comment: The `FixedLengthClassBuilder` takes only a string class name and not `<T>`, so I can't pass like that. Yes, in my second example, I get the `List<T>`, but that code can only be used if I'm hard coding the field class.

Comment: Is there a way I can convert the `List<object>` to `List<myClass>` without looping? I tried automapper, but it won't work. Even the `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` doesn't work. Right now, it's not a blocker for me, as I'm looping the records, but it would be great if I can do it in a single line of code! Any suggestions would help me digging my brain :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Cast<T>()` (with the desired class inserted for T):

```
var parseResult = fileHelperEngine.ReadFileAsList(fileName).Cast<T>();
// if desired then add .ToList() or .ToArray()
```

Comment: T should be known to the OP, I guess.

Comment: `const string className = "My_Dynamic_Class";` implies it doesn't..  It will only work if a certain base class is known.. in this case `Object`

Comment: @PeterB I tried and it gives this error `Unable to cast object of type 'My_Dynamic_Class' to type 'myNameSpace.myDTOClassName'`

Comment: the `My_Dynamic_Class` is a temp name that is used by the FileHelper in memory to create the class with dynamic field length I believe. I can give that as `what_ever_name_I_want`

Comment: Would it be possible to use `FixedFileEngine<T>`? See http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FixedFileEngine_1.htm